# Email-based DCV Issue (multiple domains) - Amazon Certificate Manager (ACM)

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl-certificate

Is there a way to validate domain control without using the email process? As I need to be able to add additional domains to the certificate for new clients...

The problem I'm facing is I can't add to the existing AWS certificate and have to create a new one with all the domains. When I do that everyone for every domain get's emailed and asked to confirm at:

```
administrator@domain.com
hostmaster@domain.com
admin@domain.com
postmaster@domain.com
webmaster@domain.com
```

So I have had to register a seperate certificate and upload it to ACM instead which is not ideal. Mainly as it's limited to 99 domains and was hoping to automate the whole process.

Is this possible with AWS?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Q: Are any other methods for validating a domain or approving a certificate supported?
>
> Not at this time.
>
> https://aws.amazon.com/certificate-manager/faqs/#provisioning

Having so many domains on one certificate isn't really a good practice, for other reasons, as well.

You're making your certificate physically longer and longer, wasting some amount of bandwidth, because the cert is sent to every connecting client, on every new connection.

Renewals will also be messy, if any of the domains on the cert are no longer pointing to your site, because auto-renewal requires that the issued cert be reachable on the Internet **for each hostname**.

> ACM tries to automatically renew your Amazon-issued SSL/TLS certificates before they expire so that no action is required from you. To renew your certificate automatically, the following must be true:
>
> - ACM must be able to establish an HTTPS connection with each domain in the certificate.
> - For each connection, the certificate that is returned must match the one that ACM is renewing.
>
> http://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/configure-domain-for-automatic-validation.html

One cleaner solution (the one I am using) is to provision each domain's cert individually, and attach each one to its own CloudFront distribution, pointing that to your origin server (which I assume in this context to be an ELB) and whitelisting all headers for forwarding to the origin, which bypasses caching and causes CloudFront to function as a simple but distributed reverse proxy.  Setting "compress objects automatically" in CloudFront may also save some bandwidth charges, and even with caching disabled, CloudFront should improve the responsiveness of your sites by keeping traffic on the AWS network for more of the path between origin and viewer.